# mySQL drop unique key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure how drop unique key constraint in mySql.

```
create table Lesson
(
  lessonId            int not null auto_increment,
  friendlyId          varchar(255) not null,
  primary key (lessonId),
  unique key friendlyId (friendlyId)
);
```

I have tried this but its a syntax error for mySql:

```
alter table Lesson
drop constraint friendlyId;
```

Answer (score 3):

Drop the index with the unique constraint and recreate the index without unique constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP INDEX index_name;
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name (columns);
```

in your case:

```
ALTER TABLE Lesson DROP INDEX friendlyId;
ALTER TABLE Lesson ADD INDEX friendlyId (friendlyId);
```